# How to end thread when exception occurs?

Tags: .net, multithreading, exception

I read many solution over here and other places but never got it right. I kinda feel embarrassed just by asking this but here I'm...

My code:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                MyClass SomeData = new MyClass()
                Thread ProcessThread = new Thread(c => StartService(SomeData));
                ProcessThread.Start();
        }

private void StartService(MyClass someData)
        {
            try
            {
                //System.Exception throws in this Execute method
                someData.Execute();
            }
            catch(Exception Ex)
            {
                Show(Ex);
//Informing me some exception occurred.
            }
        }
```

When an exception is thrown in Excute method (which, currently I'm throwing it deliberately to test), I CANNOT `abort` or `end` the thread and start ANOTHER to run SAME method. So, basically if I would like to  END that thread and then RE-RUN it again. If you think re-running is risky, I will put up a question that waits a human confirmation whether to re-run or end it. Anyways, I cannot even END it and the thread stays doing nothing at `Thread ProcessThread = new Thread(c => StartService(SomeData));` line.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Your thread already exits when after _Show(Ex)_.

Answer (score 2):

The call to

```
Show(Ex);
```

seems to imply a UI action.  If that is true, and of Show() does not properly marshal that UI action, perhaps an unhandled exception is being thrown as a result.

Other than that observation, your thread should end on it's own after Show() exits, since there are no more statements in the thread's method afterwards.  You don't have to do anything (nor should you) to manually end the thread.  Except under rather unusual circumstances, it is best to allow threads to end themselves (sometimes by sending them a signal to end, or in this case, by just letting the method run to completion).

In your `catch` block you can certainly kick off a new thread

```
Thread ProcessThread = new Thread(c => StartService(SomeData));
```

Note that this `ProcessThread` is in a different scope than the one in your code since they are both defined within a method.  If you want to be able to access that variable across your class, perhaps promote it to a class method.

Answer (score 0):

The `Thread` will exit automatically as soon as `StartService` completes.  You don't need to do anything to "end" it.

If you wish to start a new thread, you could do that directly within your method:

```
    private void StartService(MyClass someData)
    {
        try
        {
            //System.Exception throws in this Execute method
            someData.Execute();
        }
        catch(Exception Ex)
        {
            Show(Ex);
            // "Restart" this thread
            (new Thread(c => StartService(SomeData))).Start();
        }
    }
```

You may want to consider putting in some logic to prevent a thread from constantly restarting itself, however.  One option would be to keep a counter of the number of times it's restarted, and if it restarts more than a couple of times, exit gracefully after logging.  This would prevent an exception that's raised immediately from just pumping threads in and out constantly...

Comment: I tryied this but when something goes wrong again, it will say (new Thread(c => StartService(SomeData))).Start(); in here

Comment: Thank you. I might have an idea to make your suggestion very useful